# Force reload of UITableView - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBar application. There are 2 UIViewControllers A and B. UIViewController B has UITableView. I call method in A UIViewController from B UIViewController: [b someMethod:someObject];

Here is code:

```
-(void) someMethod:someObject
{
  [tableViewDataArray addObject: someObject];
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```

But UITableView doesn't reload until I switch UIViewController to B; How to reload it without switching? If this possible

Comment: Are you sure the UIViewController B object is not nil inside UIViewController A? This would fail silently.

Comment: `I call method in A UIViewController from B UIViewController: [b someMethod:someObject];`

It's not clear what you mean here. You say you call a method in "A", but you're clearly sending a message to "B". It's also not clear what you mean by:

`UITableView doesn't reload until I switch UIViewController to B`

UIViewController is a class. It doesn't switch to anything. Giving us more sample code would help us a lot.

Comment: B UIViewController initialized, i'm sure. I mean i call method in A UIViewController that implemented in B UIViewCOntroller

Comment: By switching I mean switching tabs in UITabBarController. I've put breakpoint in 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
and in [b someMethod:someObject];
Breakpoint in someMethod works immediately. But breakpoint in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath works only when i switch UIViewController B with UITabBarItem.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  I'm not being snarky; it just might help someone better answer your question if the context is fleshed out a little.

Comment: I want to add new created cell to dictionary, for reusing it in future. Simple reusing is bad method for me. Because i've got UIProgressView in each cell. And simple cell reuse is mixing UIProgressView values.

Comment: When i reload my tableView in [someMehod:someObject], i reuse cell. if my dictionary doesn't contain cell, i create new and add it into dictionary

Answer (score 1):

your best solution is to put a button on the toolbar for adding and refreshing and make a function called `add()` and connect it to the button. and inside there you do :

```
-(void) add:someObject
{
[tableViewDataArray addObject: someObject];
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

I was having a similar issue and this actually worked, this should help : [How to Reload a UITableView While I am Looking at It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661031/how-to-reload-a-uitableview-while-i-am-looking-at-it)

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBarController` doesn't load all its tabs' views until they are actually needed, so your table view probably doesn't even exist (i.e. is `nil`) before you switch to the tab that contains it.

While you *could* force the view controller to load its view hierarchy by accessing its `view` property, I wouldn't recommend it. What's the point of reloading an invisible table view anyway?

Comment: And in low memory situations, when the other tableView on the other view controller is not visible, the OS may decide to release that other table view

Comment: B UIViewController and UITableView is not nil.

Comment: Still, as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is only called for visible rows, it makes perfect sense that it isn't called at all if the entire table view is not visible.

Comment: Solve what? I don't really see the problem here, why do you need the table view to load cells when it isn't visible?

Comment: I want to add new created cell to dictionary, for reusing it in future. Simple reusing is bad method for me. Because i've got UIProgressView in each cell. And simple cell reuse is mixing UIProgressView values.

Comment: When i reload my tableView in [someMehod:someObject], i reuse cell. if my dictionary doesn't contain cell, i create new and add it into dictionary

Comment: Bad idea. Use the normal reuse mechanism of `UITableView` and simply store the progress values in your dictionary. When you dequeue a cell, simply assign the progress value from the dictionary to the `UIProgressIndicator` in the cell you dequeued. Anything else is a waste of memory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3561/discussion-between-timur-mustafaev-and-omz)